# calculating same ADR in D and lower timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i have a Indicator which is using the same ADR variable for other calculations. My problem is, that i can not achieve the same calculation result of the ADR. It is on Daily Chart different then in e.g. 5m Chart.

How can i get the same result?

The debugging variable outputs can be seen in the data-window on the right side

```
//@version=5
indicator("ADR-TEST", shorttitle="ADR-Test")

ticker_D = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session.regular)
[day_high, day_low] = request.security(ticker_D,'D',[high,low])

daily_range = day_high - day_low
adr = ta.sma(daily_range, 10)

plot(adr, "adr", display = display.data_window)
plot(daily_range, "daily_range", display = display.data_window)
plot(daily_range[1], "daily_range1", display = display.data_window)
plot(daily_range[2], "daily_range2", display = display.data_window)
plot(daily_range[3], "daily_range3", display = display.data_window)
plot(daily_range[4], "daily_range4", display = display.data_window)
plot(daily_range[5], "daily_range5", display = display.data_window)
```

In the screen you see the array data of daily_range in daily chart and lower timeframe chart. So why this is different?
[image: lower timeframe]
[image: Daily Chart]

But If i plot the lines around the last days highs and lows, it shows ithat it gets the right values

```
highLine = line.new(bar_index - 1, day_high, bar_index, day_high, extend = extend.both, color = color.green)
lowLine = line.new(bar_index - 1, day_low, bar_index, day_low, extend = extend.both, color = color.green)
highLine1 = line.new(bar_index - 1, day_high[1], bar_index, day_high[1], extend = extend.both, color = color.red)
lowLine1 = line.new(bar_index - 1, day_low[1], bar_index, day_low[1], extend = extend.both, color = color.red)
highLine2 = line.new(bar_index - 1, day_high[2], bar_index, day_high[2], extend = extend.both, color = color.rgb(0, 255, 255))
lowLine2 = line.new(bar_index - 1, day_low[2], bar_index, day_low[2], extend = extend.both, color = color.rgb(0, 255, 255))
line.delete(highLine[1])
line.delete(highLine1[1])
line.delete(lowLine[1])
line.delete(lowLine1[1])
line.delete(lowLine[2])
line.delete(lowLine1[2])
```

Comment: Are you using chatGPT? Due to such poor accuracy Stackoverflow has [banned ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). TradingView has also decided [not to provide support](http://tradingview.com/chart/TRAIA/XwwZ70ar-Our-take-on-AI-generated-Pine-Script/) for ChatGPT.

Comment: no this is my code, why are you asking this question?

Comment: If you are not honest, I don't think you will get help...

Comment: i am honest, i need the same calculation of adr in daily and lower tf

Comment: Any Ideas? is it so called repainting? How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help others: here is my solution which is working on all time frames

@Gu5tavo71: i am very disappointed by your nonsense comments

```
ticker_D = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session.regular)

daily_range_array = array.new_float(size=11)
array.set(daily_range_array,0,0.0)
array.set(daily_range_array,1,request.security(ticker_D, 'D', high[1] - low[1]))
array.set(daily_range_array,2,request.security(ticker_D, 'D', high[2] - low[2]))
array.set(daily_range_array,3,request.security(ticker_D, 'D', high[3] - low[3]))
array.set(daily_range_array,4,request.security(ticker_D, 'D', high[4] - low[4]))
array.set(daily_range_array,5,request.security(ticker_D, 'D', high[5] - low[5]))
array.set(daily_range_array,6,request.security(ticker_D, 'D', high[6] - low[6]))
array.set(daily_range_array,7,request.security(ticker_D, 'D', high[7] - low[7]))
array.set(daily_range_array,8,request.security(ticker_D, 'D', high[8] - low[8]))
array.set(daily_range_array,9,request.security(ticker_D, 'D', high[9] - low[9]))
array.set(daily_range_array,10,request.security(ticker_D, 'D', high[10] - low[10]))

adr = array.sum(daily_range_array)/10
```